# IPython Notebook not opening; throws "Symbol Not Found" error

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pyzmq

I can't seem to open IPython Notebook from terminal. I receive the following error:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
  Referenced from: /Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Does anyone have suggestions for solutions? [There is a thread on Conda's Google Group without any replies.](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/2Ywv6ggdIo4)

IPython runs in the terminal with `$ Ipython`. `$ Ipython notebook` is giving the issue.

Comment: reinstall Anaconda. Looks like there is a missing symbol in one of the shared libraries (C code), it might be error of packager or outdated library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to completely uninstall and reinstall Anaconda.

I deleted all Anaconda directories (both for specific users and at root). I then downloaded Anaconda from Continuum's website and reinstalled. It works now.

Comment: I don't like that this is the answer, but it definitely worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You probably could have fixed it with `conda install -f pyzmq`.

Comment: I tried this, upon having the same problem, and it didn't work.